# Como selecionar opções em em aplicação console com java?

Tags: java, console, console-application

Existe a possibilidade do usuário selecionar as opções do menu, navegando com as setas do teclado para cima e baixo, depois pressionando enter?

```
public static void menu() 
 {
 print("=====MENU=====");
 print("|Novo jogo   |");
 print("|Créditos    |");
 print("|Sair        |");
 print("==============");
 }
```

Eu vejo isso em vários terminais, mas não sei se isso se aplica em ConsoleApplication java.

Exemplo Angular:

[image]

Comment: Sim, é possível, mas tem um enorme trabalho para conseguir isto.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, ajudou tipo em nada.